# Add different variables in two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a little bit of help here. I am a new python coder. I need a lot of help. So, I want to add the different variables in two dictionaries. An example is:

```
x = {'a':1, 'b':2}

y = {'b':1, 'c':2}
```

I want to replace these values such that it looks like:

```
x = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':0}

y = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}
```

The order of variables has to be same. Please help me.

Comment: There **is no order** in the first place. `>>> {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}`
`{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}`

Comment: I saw this question yesterday... I'll try find the link

Comment: @Haidro It's similar to that one but now order is involved

Comment: @jamylak True, I guess.

Comment: I posted the comment yesterday, but am facing a problem so posted with the problem...

Answer (score 5):

The first thing is, that Python dicts are unordered, but if you need ordering you can use [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html?highlight=ordered#collections.OrderedDict).

But for normal dicts you can add more entries in this way:

```
x = {'a':1, 'b':2}
y = {'b':1, 'c':2}
x.update({'c':0})
y.update({'b':1})
```

Or this way:

```
x.update(c=0)
y.update(b=1)
```

Or (comment by iamthepiguy) in this way:

```
x['c'] = 0
y['b'] = 1
```

If you want to update/add many entries at the same time you could use this:

```
x.update({'c':0,'d':5,'x':4}
# or the same in the other way
x.update(c=0,d=5,x=4)
```

You can also change entries with the methods showed above. Simply use a key that is already in the dict and a new value eg. `x['a']=7`.

For more informations about dict.update look [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)

Comment: Or simply `x = {'a':1, 'b':2}` `x['c'] = 0`.

Comment: That's right, I have added it with yet another way to the answer.

Comment: I am planning to handle a minimum of 100 cariables. So, it will be very long till I use a looping statement.

Comment: You can give the `dict.update` method more than one entry to add or use a loop (look http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html in the Python docs)

Answer (score 3):

For an OrderedDict example:

```
import collections

dx = {'a':1, 'b':2}
dy = {'b':1, 'c':2}

dx['c'] = 0
dy['a'] = 0

x = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dx.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])) # lambda sorts dictionary items by key, and puts in ordered dictionary
y = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dy.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

The result of this is:

```
>>> x
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 0)])
>>> y
OrderedDict([('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)])
```

Hope that answers your question.